# Code highlighting with E4X XML literals in ActionScript code blocks

Tags: bug, status-deferred, syntax-highlighting

When entering XML literals using E4X syntax in ActionScript the code highlighting can be broken:

```
package
{

public class XMLTest
{
    public function XMLTest()
    {
       // here highlighting works ok
       var aVariable:int = 0;
       var aSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

        var xmlFragment:XML = 
        <root>
           <node />
           <node />
           <node />
        </root>;

       // from now on all code highlighting is borked
       var otherVariable:int = 0;
       var yetAnother:Sprite = new Sprite();
    }
}
}
```

There is a workaround:

```
package
{

public class XMLTest
{
    public function XMLTest()
    {
       // here highlighting works ok
       var aVariable:int = 0;
       var aSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

        var xmlFragment:XML = 
        <root>
           <node />
           <node />
           <node />
        </root>; // / //<-- resets the parser and code remains valid

       var otherVariable:int = 0;
       var yetAnother:Sprite = new Sprite();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We just deployed the latest trunk of prettify.js ; revision 83

http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/prettify.js

Comment: But we still can't specify the language in our posts.

Comment: When can we expect to specify the language as an 'advanced' feature so as to fix these syntax highlighting problems?

Answer (score -1):

I have rarely seen it work with non-trivial Perl code.

Which is one language Prettify is supposed to work with.

---

It is difficult to get a parser to parse Perl correctly, but Prettify doesn't even work for "Quote like operators".

---

```
for( qw( a b c ) ){ ... }
for( qw[ a b c ] ){ ... }
for( qw{ a b c } ){ ... }
for( qw/ a b c / ){ ... }
```

Should be highlighted more like this:

```
for( qw' a b c ' ){ ... }
```

All of those examples do **exactly** the same thing.

I Will also note that they **all** highlight correctly using Gedit.

Comment: Parsing the vomit after eating alphabet soup is never going to be easy. Especially not when trying to support every other language as well.

Comment: Haha, Perl sucks! (Sorry Perl guys)

Comment: @Rich I am so using this line in the future

Comment: jjnguy's comment is obviously supposed to be a joke.

Comment: Prettify has never claimed that it works with perl.  Though I'm happy to accept patches.

Comment: It highlights `use` correctly which as far as I know is *only* used by Perl.